# PHP - saber erro offset

Tags: php

Existe alguma variavel que mostra se existe erro de offset no php, mas sem exibir na tela ? tipo uma função que avalia ?
Obrigado

Comment: Geralmente se faz um teste com o `isset()`, `if(isset($arr['index']){ ... `

Comment: Atualmente uso `&$array[$key]`. Mas eu recomendo usar o `isset()`

Comment: não existe algo que verifica se ira imprimir na tela ? tipo uma função log que posso verificar ?

Comment: Qual é o erro específico que você quer evitar? Elemento inexistente de array? Coloca mais informações que fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 8  esse é o erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria assim, mostraria nos logs e na tela não exibiria:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

se trocar o 0(zero) pelo 1, mostrará na tela também.

Comment: Mas e para verificar em um if ? tipo if($existeerro == true {} Como faria ?

Comment: O correto é você desenvolver mostrando todos os erros e tratar isso antes, porque você quer verificar se existe erro em um if?

Comment: pois tem um caso que preciso redirecionar, para uma segunda maneira de ser feita tipo se erro = 0 ok caso erro metodo2

Comment: Então acho que seria algo como o @rray citou acima: if(!isset($arr['index']){} negando o isset.

Comment: mas não é sempre que ocorre o erro ...

Comment: posta algum exemplo do código seu, para que possamos entender melhor o que você ta querendo.